# React Native Gradle fails with `java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)`

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

### Problem

On a brand new react native project (created with `create-react-native-app`), the gradle build fails.

### Output

#### --debug

`$ cd android/
$ ./gradlew build --debug`

gives this output (truncated to the error point)

```
16:17:09.777 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager]      InputStream: OriginalStream{jarFiles=[], folders=[], scopes=[SUB_PROJECTS], contentTypes=[CLASSES], dependencies=[prepareDebugDependencies, build dependencies configuration ':app:_debugApk' all dependencies]}
16:17:09.777 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager]      InputStream: OriginalStream{jarFiles=[], folders=[], scopes=[SUB_PROJECTS_LOCAL_DEPS], contentTypes=[CLASSES], dependencies=[prepareDebugDependencies, build dependencies configuration ':app:_debugApk' all dependencies]}
16:17:09.777 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager]      InputStream: OriginalStream{jarFiles=[], folders=[/Users/noel/w/crna-test/android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug], scopes=[PROJECT], contentTypes=[CLASSES], dependencies=[compileDebugJavaWithJavac]}
16:17:09.777 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager]      OutputStream: IntermediateStream{rootLocation=/Users/noel/w/crna-test/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/debug, scopes=[PROJECT, PROJECT_LOCAL_DEPS, SUB_PROJECTS, SUB_PROJECTS_LOCAL_DEPS, EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES], contentTypes=[DEX], dependencies=[transformClassesWithDexForDebug]}
16:17:09.778 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project :app - Registering model element 'tasks.transformClassesWithDexForDebug' (hidden = false)
16:17:09.793 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:17:09.793 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:17:09.793 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:17:09.793 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
16:17:09.793 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
16:17:09.793 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
16:17:09.793 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:17:09.793 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
16:17:09.793 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
16:17:09.795 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
16:17:09.795 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
16:17:09.795 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
16:17:09.795 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 6.915 secs
```

#### --stacktrace

and the stacktrace is

`$ ./gradlew build --stacktrace`

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:540)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:93)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:121)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.DefaultNdkInfo.findTargetPlatformVersionOrLower(DefaultNdkInfo.java:167)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.DefaultNdkInfo.findLatestPlatformVersion(DefaultNdkInfo.java:89)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getPlatformVersion(NdkHandler.java:131)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.supports64Bits(NdkHandler.java:234)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getSupportedAbis(NdkHandler.java:297)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.StripDebugSymbolTransform.<init>(StripDebugSymbolTransform.java:86)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createStripNativeLibraryTask(TaskManager.java:1342)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager.createTasksForVariantData(ApplicationTaskManager.java:289)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createTasksForVariantData(VariantManager.java:485)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$3.call(VariantManager.java:293)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$3.call(VariantManager.java:290)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.java:44)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:286)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$11.call(BasePlugin.java:688)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$11.call(BasePlugin.java:685)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:683)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:608)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:605)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$1(BasePlugin.java:603)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
        ... 44 more
```

### .gradles

#### root

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

#### app

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.crnatest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

### Environment

- `npm ls react-native-scripts`: `(empty)`
- `npm ls react-native`: `react-native@0.52.0`
- `npm ls expo`: `(empty)`
- `node -v`: `v8.3.0`
- `npm -v`: `5.6.0`
- `yarn --version`: `0.21.3`
- `watchman version`: `"version": "4.7.0"`
- Operating system: macOS 10.13.3

### Reproducible Demo

https://github.com/noelweichbrodt/crna-test

Comment: Hi Noel did you got any solution for this ? I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem when building on Mac but not Windows (using gradle `2.2.3` as well). the only thing I found that helped was to downgrade the gradle version to `2.1.2`. Not 100% sure why this works but it does. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea will it helpful for someone or not but my problem was resolved by adding required (they were used in `build.gradle`) but missed variables to .env